# Insert in Sybase ASE primary key duplicate

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have been trying to insert data in a Sybase Database from an external script.

I am using the exact Querys as the original program is using. When i insert the sql's as the original program does it all looks fine. Until i try to insert the data manually inside the program; it gives me an error

> Error to executeSolUpdates Error executing update: [ERROR CODE: E0001]
>   Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object `changes` with
>   unique index `pk_27471`

I suspect that by inserting externally the PK value is not beeing changed and the original script is trying to insert the new data with the unique key i just used.

Is this data saved in the sybase database? and how can i insert the files and use the autoincrement function?

If i insert "null" instead of a value it tells me i cannot use NULL. But when i dont put the PK column in the insert sql at all it will return the duplicate entry.

Could someone give their view on this issue?

Comment: See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions on how to improve your chances of receiving a timely and useful answer; for example, what are the actual insert statements you and the program are supplying to ASE? what columns make up unique index `pk_27471`? you mention `autoincrement` sooo ... does this mean you have an identity column defined in the table? have you verified that your insert is failing because there actually **IS** a row already in the table with the same values for the `pk_27471` index columns?

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for your comment. My knowledge of Sybase is not sufficient to be sure about these facts. This issue is not only one insert SQL but with with different querys.